# Which file needs to change to set "network-id.clients.client-id.channel" while seting up hyperledger explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-explorer

I am new to blockchain and I am trying to run Hyperledger Explorer by using official document but I got stuck with below point in Readme file of explorer

Fabric Configure Hyperledger Explorer

**point 3 :Modify "network-id.clients.client-id.channel" to your default channel for each client**

I won't able to understand that in which file I need to make change for this.
Because of this I received below error.

postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
(node:13952) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
{ Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service discovery.Discovery
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/your/path/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/your/path/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/your/path/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/your/path/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
    at callback (/your/path/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
  code: 12,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'unknown service discovery.Discovery' }
Received kill signal, shutting down gracefully
Closed out connections

Answer (score 0):

The file to be edited is blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json.

Eg:

```
"network-configs": {
      "network-1": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "clients": {
          "client-1": {
            "tlsEnable": true,
            "organization": "UserOrg",
            "channel": "mychannel",
            "credentialStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_UserOrg/credential",
              "cryptoStore": {
                "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_UserOrg/crypto"
              }
            }
          }
        }
...
```